# Error while installing Firefox Developer Edition on 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, firefox, ubuntu-make

So i have the normal Firefox Quantum65.0 installed on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I want to install Firefox developer edition.

I have already tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

But it simply re-installs the normal firefox. So i tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

And when i run `umake web firefox-dev`
i get `Choose installation path: /home/me/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev`
And when i press Enter i get the following error:

```
ERROR: One default was already registered, can't register a second one in that choices set: ['en-US', 'en-US', 'ach', 'af', 'sq', 'ar', 'an', 'hy-AM', 'as', 'ast', 'az', 'eu', 'be', 'bn-BD', 'bn-IN', 'bs', 'br', 'bg', 'my', 'ca', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW', 'hr', 'cs', 'da', 'nl', 'en-GB', 'en-CA', 'en-ZA', 'en-US', 'eo', 'et', 'fi', 'fr', 'fy-NL', 'ff', 'gd', 'gl', 'ka', 'de', 'el', 'gn', 'gu-IN', 'he', 'hi-IN', 'hu', 'is', 'id', 'ia', 'ga-IE', 'it', 'ja', 'kab', 'kn', 'cak', 'kk', 'km', 'ko', 'lv', 'lij', 'lt', 'dsb', 'mk', 'mai', 'ms', 'ml', 'mr', 'ne-NP', 'nb-NO', 'nn-NO', 'oc', 'or', 'fa', 'pl', 'pt-BR', 'pt-PT', 'pa-IN', 'ro', 'rm', 'ru', 'sr', 'si', 'sk', 'sl', 'son', 'es-AR', 'es-CL', 'es-MX', 'es-ES', 'sv-SE', 'ta', 'te', 'th', 'tr', 'uk', 'hsb', 'ur', 'uz', 'vi', 'cy', 'xh']
ERROR: Unhandled exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 158, in wrapper
    function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/frameworks/web.py", line 116, in get_metadata_and_check_license
    UI.delayed_display(TextWithChoices(_("Choose language: {}".format(default_label)), languages, True))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/interactions/__init__.py", line 59, in __init__
    raise BaseException(message)
BaseException: One default was already registered, can't register a second one in that choices set: ['en-US', 'en-US', 'ach', 'af', 'sq', 'ar', 'an', 'hy-AM', 'as', 'ast', 'az', 'eu', 'be', 'bn-BD', 'bn-IN', 'bs', 'br', 'bg', 'my', 'ca', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW', 'hr', 'cs', 'da', 'nl', 'en-GB', 'en-CA', 'en-ZA', 'en-US', 'eo', 'et', 'fi', 'fr', 'fy-NL', 'ff', 'gd', 'gl', 'ka', 'de', 'el', 'gn', 'gu-IN', 'he', 'hi-IN', 'hu', 'is', 'id', 'ia', 'ga-IE', 'it', 'ja', 'kab', 'kn', 'cak', 'kk', 'km', 'ko', 'lv', 'lij', 'lt', 'dsb', 'mk', 'mai', 'ms', 'ml', 'mr', 'ne-NP', 'nb-NO', 'nn-NO', 'oc', 'or', 'fa', 'pl', 'pt-BR', 'pt-PT', 'pa-IN', 'ro', 'rm', 'ru', 'sr', 'si', 'sk', 'sl', 'son', 'es-AR', 'es-CL', 'es-MX', 'es-ES', 'sv-SE', 'ta', 'te', 'th', 'tr', 'uk', 'hsb', 'ur', 'uz', 'vi', 'cy', 'xh']
```

What is the problem here exactly and how do i solve it? Any help is appriciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu's official repository and Ubuntu Desktop's repository contains umake versions *16.11.1ubuntu1* and *18.05~bionic1* respectively. This seems to be a bug under that versions of umake. I installed umake from the repository of [Galileo Sartor](https://launchpad.net/~lyzardking) and all seem to work fine under that umake. This repository contains umake version *18.09+201902042247~ubuntu18.04.1* at the time of installation. That umake installed Firefox Developer Edition version 65.0b5.

- Uninstall previously installed Ubuntu make and Ubuntu Desktop's repository:

  ```
  sudo apt autoremove ubuntu-make
  sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
  ```
- To install Ubuntu make from above said repository and then firefox-dev:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
  sudo apt install ubuntu-make
  umake web firefox-dev
  ```

*This repository contains daily build versions of umake and is also mentioned in [umake - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make), so might be considered as a trusted ppa.*

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Thank you, installed succesfully but how do i add it to the launcher and dock. I have to goto the installed path to launch it everytime

Comment: @Ajo For this you need to create a Desktop Entry. Follow the answer on [How can I create launchers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222)

Answer (score 2):

Simply specify the language along with the umake command

```
umake web firefox-dev --lang en-US
```

you are welcome to replace the `--lang en-US` with the language of your choice.

Solution credits from  [Ubuntu umake issue tracker git](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/592#issuecomment-460395565)