# How to open Firefox Dev on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, firefox

I installed Firefox Dev on Ubuntu 18.04 per these instructions (marked as correct answer):
[Error while installing Firefox Developer Edition on 18.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116182/error-while-installing-firefox-developer-edition-on-18-04-1-lts?newreg=2baa081339f54b408e549f08f90808a7)

When I search for Firefox Dev, Ubuntu only turns up the Firefox browser.

And in Terminal when I type `firefox-dev --version` I get "No such command".

Comment: Does anything come up when you run `which firefox-dev` in a terminal?  That should list the path to the application if it is installed.  You might also try `locate -b firefox-dev`.  The package `firefox-dev` is available in Ubuntu repositories, so this method of installation you linked above may not be the best method:  `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install firefox-dev` should be all you have to do.

Comment: @Nmath I realized one must uninstall firefox brower, then try to install firefox developer. Thank you so much for your assistance (I'm a n00b at Linux)